# When using the Omega Responsive theme, IE7 and IE8 load all stylesheets

Tags: theming

When I view a site that I'm currently working on in IE7 or IE8, there are tons of conflicting styles. The normal stylesheet is not taking precedence over the global and narrow stylesheets which is causing problems for the layout of the site. I have aggregated both css and js to see if this was an issue with the amount of files IE will load, to no avail. I have patched the omega-mediaqueries.js with the omega-ie7 patch, this did not resolve the issue either.

I'm at a loss and I'm under the gun for time. Has anyone else encountered this issue? How can I make sure that the normal stylesheet takes precedence over the other stylesheets?

Answer (score 4):

Omega does not support responsive layouts for IE 8 & below. You will need to add [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) or a similar javascript to your theme in order to make up for IE 8 & below's lack of support for CSS media queries.

There is an [Omega issue on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1272812) related to this topic with more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however it seems as though this issue still hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Do you mean that you tried adding respond.js and it did not fix your issue, or are you just referring to the fact that the issue ticket I linked to has not been resolved? I linked to the issue ticket because there is discussion in that thread that should help you implement the respond.js fix.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the related [issue/comment](http://drupal.org/node/1272812#comment-5946156) I could fix it on my site.
This is important, you need the mentioned code too in your theme template: <?php function omega_subtheme_css_alter(&$css) { foreach ($css as $key => $value) { if (preg_match('/^ie::(\S*)/', $key)) { unset($css[$key]); } else { $css[$key]['browsers']['IE'] = TRUE; } } } ?>